# Svelte doesn't show the spinner in a conditional

Tags: javascript, svelte, reactive, svelte-component, sveltekit

I have a spinner component, which I have tested outside the if conditions. It works perfectly. However when I put it inside the if condition like in the following code, it does not show at all. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried using `$:` syntax to make the spinner variable reactive. No luck!

```
    let email = 'example@blah.com'
    let password;
    let newEmail;
    let passwordEntered;
    let emailChanged = false;
    let spinner = false;
    let error = false;  

    function cancel() {
        // Dispatch code
    }

    function updateEmail() {
        spinner = true;
        error = false; // Reset this to default

        // The code that actually updates the email goes here
        updateEmailonFirebase();

        // Error handling code
        
        // Once the email is updated, hide the spinner.
        spinner = false;
    }
</script>

<div>    
    {#if !emailChanged}
    
        {#if !passwordEntered}
            <label for="password">Please enter your password for verification</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" bind:value={password} />
            <div>
                <button on:click={cancel}>Cancel</button>
                <button on:click={() => (passwordEntered = true)}>Next</button>
            </div>
        {:else if passwordEntered && !spinner}
            <input id="newEmail" type="email" bind:value={newEmail} />
            <div>
                <button on:click={cancel}>Cancel</button>
                <button on:click={updateEmail}>Next</button>
            </div>
        {:else if passwordEntered && spinner}
            <Spinner />
        {/if}

    {:else if emailChanged}
            <p>Your email has been changed!</p>
            <!-- Using cancel here because it does the same thing -->
            <button on:click={cancel}>Go back</button>

    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: Need more details. Currently I see `updateEmail` is a sync function, it sets `spinner` to true then back to false, which is effectively no-op. Why so? It looks Suspicious.

Comment: I removed the code that updates the email. It's the standard firebase email update function call. I removed it so it doesn't take the focus away from the problem. I have updated it now.

Comment: Well, then it’s clearly as I said, change to `spinner` is no-op, `spinner` is false thus the behavior you see.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about asynchronous call in js. Search keywords: “js async-await”, “js async execution”, “js promise” etc.

Comment: to be more clear, 'updateEmailonFirebase()' looks like a async call. Your code is currently executing the next line (`spinner = false`) immediately instead of waiting for the update call to complete. You'll want to update `spinner` in `updateEmailonFirebase()` callback if it allows, or rewrite to use async await

Comment: Ah, I see. That helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the `await` keyword in front on front of the firebase function call as per the comments.

`await updateEmailonFirebase();`

I forgot that this was an async function call.

Thanks everyone.